# Extend a function - merge two functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the best way to have a Javascript 'class', for instance

```
// In the parent instance
function xyz()
{
    var x = 1;
}
```

I want to set this in the class, and when a user extends a class, I want them to effectively be extending this function. This is the user's code for instance:

```
// In the child instance
function xyz()
{
    var y = 2;
}
```

Merging should result in:

```
// In the merged instance
function xyz()
{
    var x = 1;
    var y = 2;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can't 'merge' functions as you describe them there, but what you can do is have one function be redefined to call both itself and a new function (before or after the original).

```
var xyz = function(){
   console.log('xyz');
};

var abc = function(){
   console.log('abc');
};

// and, elsewhere, if you want to merge:
var orig = abc;
abc = function(){
    orig.call(this, arguments);
    xyz.call(this, arguments);
};
```

The inclusion of `(this, arguments)` is not needed if you don't care about execution context or if the called function is parameterless. But I included for clarity of what one might do if you wanted a parameterized method.

Comment: Quick question on the use of `call` here with `arguments`. Since `arguments` is an array like structure, shouldn't be using `apply` instead of `call`?

Answer (score 9):

You tag the question with jquery, so I assume you use jquery. with jquery, you could merge objects with [jQuery.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/).

```
var object1 = {
  apple: 0,
  banana: {weight: 52, price: 100},
  cherry: 97
};
var object2 = {
  banana: {price: 200},
  durian: 100
};

/* merge object2 into object1 */
$.extend(object1, object2);
```

or use prototype chain to implement inheritance. for example:

```
function a() {
    this.t1 = 1;
    this.sayMyName = function() {
        alert('a');
    }
}
b.prototype = new a;
b.prototype.constructor = b;
function b() {
    this.t2 = 2;
    this.sayMyName = function() {
        alert('b');
    }
}
var obj = new b();
alert(obj.t1); // this would say 1
obj.sayMyName(); // this would say b
```

Comment: The prototype chain is what I am interested in - I did some quick reading on prototyping, but it didn't go in to functions. Do you know of any good reading for this?

Comment: There are multiple ways to implement class/inheritance in javascript. here are some articles about objected oriented javascript.  [3 ways to define a JavaScript class](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/)  [Object Oriented Programming in JavaScript](http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm)  [Classical Inheritance in JavaScript](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html)  hope this help :)

Answer (score 2):

```
const mergeFunctions = function () {
  let listOfFuncs = []
  for (let func of arguments) {
      listOfFuncs.push(func)
  }
  return function () {
    for (let func of listOfFuncs) {
        func(arguments)
    }
  }
}

let x = function () {
  console.log("hello");
}

let y = function () {
  console.log("world")
}
mergeFunctions(x, y)()
/////////////////////
hello
world
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can try renaming the original function and calling it within the new function:

```
// In the parent instance
function xyz()
{
    var x = 1;
}

// In the child instance
var old_xyz = xyz;
function xyz()
{
    var y = 2;
    old_xyz();
}
```

Also works with class/method inheritance:

```
MyClass.prototype.old_xyz = MyClass.prototype.xyz;
MyClass.prototype.xyz = function () {
    this.old_xyz();
}
```