# Discrepancy btw Kendo grid _event databound and option databound

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

For Kendo grid, we can use [bind](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-dataBound) to subscribe to events after initialization.

Imagine the following codes: (I got you covered if you want to try it out in [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/gilehepuhu/edit?html,js,output))

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
  function foo(e) {
    console.log("foo");
  }
  function doo(e) {
    console.log("doo");
  }
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      columns: [
        { field: "name" },
        { field: "age" }
      ],
      dataSource: [
        { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
        { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
      ],
      dataBound: foo
  });
  $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").bind("dataBound", doo);
  debugger;
})
</script>
```

At the point of debugger, I observed following in browser's console:

[image]

I saw that the bound doo only exists in the _event array. The trouble this brings is if I need to reuse this grid configuration in the following way:

```
$("newgrid").kendoGrid($("oldgrid").data("kendoGrid").options);
```

I will lose bound events. Is this a bug or I'm interpreting it in the wrong way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grid.options`are only used during grid initialization and after initialization bound event is not a part of options.

Though you can update grid `dataBound` event in options after initialization:

```
grid.setOptions({
    function(e){ foo(e); doo(e); }
})
```

Comment: Since the ultimate purpose is reuse the options, including dataBound event handler but in the meantime not overwriting the default. I finally combine [$.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) and [this idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7287066/3014916) to achieve my goal. Your comments do open up the thinking. Thank you.