# Properly merge two functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've searched around SO a bit and can't find any solutions that seem to do what I'm trying to do.  I have two objects with the some of the same properties.

```
this.defaultEvents = {
    [FOCUS]: (e) => {
        this.focusHandler(e);
    },
    [BLUR]: (e) => e
};

this.otherEvents = {
    [FOCUS]: (e) => {
        this.otherFocusHandler(e);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to merge these properties, so that somehow I get something like this...

```
this.mergedEvents = {
    [FOCUS]: (e) => {
        this.focusHandler(e);
        this.otherFocusHandler(e);
    },
    [BLUR]: (e) => e
};
```

So that I can invoke `(e) => this.mergedEvents[FOCUS](e)` and have both focus handlers be called with the same arguments.

This question seems to be the closest thing to what I'm trying to do.  I guess a call to each function should work?

[Extend a function - merge two functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286986/extend-a-function-merge-two-functions)

This temporary solution seems to work, but I guess I should be using call or apply?  I'm not too familiar with either of them.

```
const merged = {};

for(let key in defaultEvents) {

  if ( otherEvents.hasOwnProperty( key ) && typeof otherEvents[key] === 'function') {
    merged[key] = function(e) {
      defaultEvents[key](e);
      otherEvents[key](e);
    }
  }

}

merged[FOCUS]('test');
```

here's a [code pen](http://codepen.io/adjavaherian/pen/pNoQYZ) too

Comment: Short of doing some weird stuff with `eval`, there's not really a way to add stuff to an existing function. I think your best bet is to just have a function that calls two other functions...

Comment: Could you not create an object with an event handler registration method similar to addEventListener that accepts a callback?

Comment: If you want to "merge" `n` functions, you have to create a new function that calls the `n` functions.

Comment: Thanks, gonna go with the event handler registration idea.  Simpler and more to the point of what I actually want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate keys of object and create composed functions for each key, e.g.:

```
function merge(...events) {
  const all = events
    .map(e => Object.keys(e)) // map keys
    .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []); // flatten
  const unique = [...new Set(all)]; // remove duplicates
  return unique.reduce((r, key) => {
    const handlers = events
      .filter(e => e[key]) // filter out not relevant handlers
      .map(e => e[key]); // extract concrete handler
    r[key] = e => handlers.map(h => h(e)); // compose functions with map
    return r;
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: this is really cool but, I think @Scott Marcus nailed it with the event handler registration method idea.  I'm gonna go with something like that.  I'll mark this as an accepted answer since it actually does what I was imagining. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same case, this is my code in Typescript:

```js
export function mergeFunctions(...funcs) {
    return function(...args) {
        funcs.filter((fn) => !!fn).forEach(fn => fn?.(...args))
    }
}
```

Usage in your case:

```js
mergeFunctions(focusHandler, otherFocusHandler)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.toString()`, `.replace()`, `eval()`

```
var obj = {[`FOCUS`]: (e) => {
  console.log("abc")
}};

var mergedEvents = {
  [`FOCUS`]: (e) => {
    console.log(123)
  }
}

var fn = mergedEvents["FOCUS"].toString()
         .replace("console.log(123)", "console.log(123);console.log('abc')");

mergedEvents["FOCUS"] = eval(fn);
```